# Creating Authentication in Excel Addin created using Excel DNA C#

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, excel-dna

I have an Excel Add-In Created using Excel DNA C#,I want to add authentication so that unauthorized users should not be able to access it.

I've an Authentication dll which I use for my other projects as well how can i use it( Authentication dll) in This Excel Add-In?

Authentication API's are called from Start Up file in case of other applications.

which is the start up file in case of Excel DNA?? so that i can call Authentication API's from there.

Currently,I am calling the  authentication API  from the '.dna' file and it is giving an Exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you add a `public class` that implements the `ExcelDna.Integration.IExcelAddIn` interface, you'll find the `AutoOpen()` method that is called when the add-in is loaded. This is a good place to do the authentication check, and set a flag or something that disables the relevant features.